# Stuck with Foreground window

Tags: c#, windows, process, background-foreground

this is for windows desktop, not web... in C# using Visual Studio 2013. in windows 7.

hello, I'm recreating a "Windows Speech Recognizer" from scratch... si working really well...
what i need to do si for it to check what windows process are open (ie Notepad, Firefox, etc) then IF Notepad is open, do something... without having to CALL that action myself... like automatic... Open Notepad... an alert says "Hello Notepad"... I Close Notepad" an action says "Close Notepad"... I try 12948305380453 diferent things but the only thing i've acomplished is it writting a numer... and when i close and reopen notepad... the number is diferent... I need THE PROCESS NAME... like "notepad.exe" "firefox.exe" from the windows task manager...

sorry i dont have any code to post, because i dont actially have one with this part... thank you...

The program (notepad) will be open manualy so the code needs to constantly keep track of the task manager process. and give me the result in a variable inside the code (For example, string "PNAME", so i can use that variable in the rest of my code.

I only need it to tell me if Notepad.exe is open on not (ie True Or False) to usit like

If notepad.exe is open do this
If notepad.exe is closed do nothing

ok... the code ir Fairly large... so I will try to post the most relevant ones...

"usign" I'm using are...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
```

I've inizialized a speech recognition enguine that does NOT use the windows UI or it's commands (Ie if I say Open Firefox" it does nothing because it is not in his grammar)

then I'v loaded my own grammar

```
private Grammar CreateCustomGrammar()
{
    GrammarBuilder GeneralCommands = new GrammarBuilder();
    GeneralCommands.Append(new Choices("cut", "copy", "paste", "Read Clipboard", "help", "Close Recognition", "Turn Dictation On", "Read That"));
    return new Grammar(GeneralCommands);
   recognizer.LoadGrammar(GeneralCommands);
}
```

and added a switch to every word in the grammar so it knows what to do

```
private void SpeechToAction(string text)
{
    DetermineText(text);

        switch (text)
        {
            case "cut":
                //cut();
                speed();
                break;
            case "copy":
                copy();
                break;
            case "paste":
                paste();
                break;
            case "Read Clipboard":
                readClipboard();
               break;
            case "Read That":
               readThat();
               break;
            case "Turn Dictation Off":
               TurnDictationOff();
               break;
            case "help":
               help();
               break;
            case "Close Recognition":
               Exit();
               break;
        }
}
```

all of that works in the background if i want to use another application "ie Notepad"

but if there are commands that i want to be ACTIVE JUST when "notepad" IS THE FOREGROUND application... there is where im stuck

I know the Theory...

it will something like this

(before all that code i've add)

```
//here is the tricky part
      IF //notepad is the foreground and var notepadOK == 1
       {   
        private Grammar NEWNAME()
        {
            GrammarBuilder NEWNAME = new GrammarBuilder();
            GeneralCommands.Append(new Choices("Hole notepad", "save"));
            return new Grammar(NEWNAME);
            var notepadOK = 0
        }
       }
      IF //notepad is NOT in the foreground and notepadOK == 0
        {
           // unload Notepad Grammar (i remember how to do this part, just cant find //it in the code
        }
```

Comment: What technology are you using? winforms? wpf?

Comment: Please use a spell checker.

Comment: im sorry, is my first time writting in here, dont know where the spell checker is of if you are telling me to use something like Word before writting here... i really speak in spanish not english... I can understand english but not write it well...

Comment: for the tecnology... not sure either... i create a proyect in visual studio and "create Form"... but i am using it to interact with other programas like notepad while my application is still running in the background (that part works fine)

Comment: E.g. Microsoft Word has a spell checker.

Comment: my windows is in spanish... dont have spell checker for english or dont know how to change it

Answer (score 1):

In order to look for- and deal with, processes in .net you should use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class
using that you can list running processes and get information about each one

The sample for the [Process.GetProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method seems to nearly what you want, except you would do it continuously

Comment: i've tryed, but when i write "process" it stays in black, not blue... and is underlined in red... like if it doesnt exist...

Comment: You need to add the proper namespace: `using System.Diagnostics` and also use a capital "P" in "process"

Comment: Yes, that is helpful :) generally on SO you should try and post code or examples of what you're doing, that way people will be able to give you better awsers

Comment: thank you all for your responses... sadly i couldn't get any of them work, mostly because i dont know how, or where to use this "Process.GetProcesses()"

Comment: I already used "using System.Diganostics" is on the first post

Comment: I've found a tutorial on youtube that helped me... thanks all of you for your responses... really appriciate (now, to study english so i can write better questions/answenrs :P)